# How to import javascript file specific to a particular angular component

Tags: angular

I could specify this file path in angular.json but as I understand from there it will be globally included to all the components.

I just want to import particular js file only in the dashboard component.

dashboard.components.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@import url('../../../node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following ways

```
declare var $: any;

import '../../../node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.js';
export class MemMonComponent {
    createSomething() {
        $("#yourelement").html('');
    }
}
```

must do it into `AfterViewInit`